# Washed Out Controls with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, windows-7, colors, controls

I recently upgraded my system to Windows 7 Professional.  Furthermore, I recently upgraded from VB6 to VB.NET and I've been working with forms and control under the new interface.  Controls such as text boxes and tab controls are washed out and very difficult to see.

In my attempt to remedy the situation, I personalized my display by unchecking the box under "Windows Color" entitled "Enable transparency" and adjusting the Color Intensity slider all the way to the right.  But no matter what I try to do, I still get washed-out form colors.

Is there a setting for adjusting the default form colors?  What am I missing?

Comment: can we please see some code if you dont mind..

Comment: Some screenshots of your washed out controls would be useful.

Comment: Here's a screenshot:  http://i249.photobucket.com/albums/gg203/SpacemanSpiff_Steve/Washed-OutControls.png

Comment: i dont see anything wash out.. can you tell me which one in the screen shot..

Comment: What's washed out in that screenshot? The Windows Forms designer doesn't support Aero transparency. You have to run the application to get that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you have a couple of choices, all of which you probably won't like.

1. Change your Textbox BorderStyle from Fixed3D to FixedSingle, this will give you a more pronounced border around the textboxes (no such property on comboboxes though). This will also make your textboxes look a lot more 'flat', which you may not want.
2. Change either the background of your form or the background of your controls, thereby providing a better contrast between the two. Even slight variations on the same color would help.
3. Purchase (or make your own) custom controls that have built-in style changing abilities. I use the Telerik controls sometimes. They have the ability to let you change the UI Element's styles, including all kinds of colors and different borders and such. The issue with this option is a lot of these custom controls are overly expensive, although you can find decent ones for fairly cheap sometimes (I found a control set once that was pretty nice for $19).

Whatever you decide to do, you have to remember that your form will look different to users that are using different operating systems than what you're developing on. You noticed a big change when you went from (I'm assuming) Windows XP to Windows 7 right? You have to remember to test your application on all operating systems that your application will be expected to run on. You could design it beautifully on Windows 7 and it may look horrible on XP. You may be able to ignore OSs that are older than XP, but for the time being almost 50% of users still use XP (last I checked).

BTW, there is no setting for adjusting the default form colors... this just happens to be how forms look on Windows 7. I found it an adjustment when I went from XP to Win7, but you get used to it. I very rarely make the background of my controls the same color as the background of my form just because of this... oh, and don't go changing your display, you want to see what your users are going to see - otherwise you'll end up with something that only looks good on your computer. :)

Comment: There are definitely settings for adjusting the default window color in Windows 7. Right-click on the desktop, select "Personalize", click "Window Color", then click "Advanced appearance settings..." Customize just as you did in Windows XP. I very much recommend against using or purchasing custom controls. The built-in ones are just fine, and conform with user expectations. Every 3rd party control library that I've seen is terribly broken.

Comment: @CodyGray      The poster was talking about default form colors, not windows colors and there is no default FORM color adjustment that I'm aware of. Also, I agree that 3rd party controls are buggy at times, but sometimes the benefits outweigh the drawbacks.

Comment: Sure there is. It's called "3D Objects". Click on the "OK" button in the little sample image. That color becomes the color of all 3D objects, including forms. It used to be (and still is, in the Classic theme) a medium gray color. In the Aero theme, it's an extremely light gray, almost white. I usually turn the brightness down a tad. Assuming you don't mess with the colors in the WinForms designer (which [you shouldn't](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/12/6648399.aspx)), your changes there will show up in all apps, including yours.

Comment: @CodyGray       What you're referring to is how to change your operating system's colors... what I believe the poster was asking is how to change the colors of the form that he is designing. Do you expect all of your users to change their operating system's colors to make your application look good?